# Add comments to a wordpress blog using json api in bottle python

Tags: python, wordpress, wordpress-json-api

Python: I have to add comments on wordpress blog using json wordpress api. Json api plugin is already installed on wordpress application. I have already get blog content using json api. Need to put comments for the blog now.
Any way to do this!